# How to implement search function on Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to have a simple search function be it a bar or what ever with suggestion or do you call it autocomplete. And when i tab/click on these suggestions, it brings me to the xml(layouts) pages i already created.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Is your actual question how to display a search box when the user hits the search button? Or is it how to search a document collection? These are two entirely different questions. Please be more specific.

Comment: Code for the search function? None so far, i am newbie in Android. But i have lots of xml created in my layout needs them to be searchable.
An example i found http://dict.leo.org/bilder/android/s4abb2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can implement search interface using the search dialog or the search widget ,Please check this for details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html